# Have docker create every volume as a separate ZFS filesystem

Tags: docker, zfs

I enabled [Docker's ZFS Storage Driver](https://docs.docker.com/storage/storagedriver/zfs-driver/), but apparently it only deals with Docker internals, using ZFS snapshots and clones for its own overlays.

But what I want is for Docker to create every volume, especially persistent ones, as their own ZFS filesystems, so that I can independently snapshot them for backup purposes.

Is there a Docker option to enable this feature? I would like to avoid having to manually create every volume of every application and bind mount them.

I found [this plugin](https://github.com/TrilliumIT/docker-zfs-plugin) but it seems very little used.

Comment: The last commit was just a couple months ago for that plugin, so I am not sure I would agree that is not well maintained. Also it  doesn't seem like it would be a very complicated plugin. Just creating/destroying datasets as needed. That said, I haven't used it, so I don't know if it is good or not.

Answer (score 1):

I decided to use [that plugin](https://github.com/TrilliumIT/docker-zfs-plugin). It seems to work.